# What does the Rust syntax `if let [.., last] = self ...` mean?

Tags: rust, syntax

I'm reading the source code for the Rust standard library and came across this code from [`std::slice`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.48.0/library/core/src/slice/mod.rs#L239-L241).

```rust
pub fn last(&self) -> Option<&T> {
    if let [.., last] = self { Some(last) } else { None }
}
```

What does `[.., last]` mean? I couldn't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [pattern matching on slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/slice-patterns.html).

`[.., last]` in particular means "bind the last element of a slice to variable `last`"

Comment: Probably worth mentioning (ir)refutability.

Comment: Thanks. "rust slice pattern" helped with the search. I also learned "named sub-slice" and such.